# My turtle is pregnant what do I do?

Tags: breeding, turtles

I recently got a turtle at the pet store for free because she is to large to fit in their tank after someone left her there. (8 inch shell length) A few days later after we had her She layed an egg and a couple hours later accidentally cracked it, so we had to throw it out. She has not layed an egg since and its been a day, should I be worried? And, we placed her in the bathtub with half water and half sand about 2-3 inch and don't have space for more and right now sand is all we have, and I want her to lay her eggs so she wont die from infection or so, what do I do?

Comment: Were all the turtles in the pet store kept in the same tank? aka. Is it reasonable to assume that the eggs are fertilized?

Comment: Als, do you happen to know what species of turtle it is? Red/yellow eared slider? Box turtle?

Answer (score 4):

So, turtles have eggs in their bodies that go through stages and cycles. While the eggs are in the body is when the male fertilizes those eggs BUT a male is not a necessary factor for the eggs to be dropped. She may have had unfertilized eggs drop. Also, if she has been with a male before, just like some fish she can hold in male sperm and later lay fertilized eggs. Most turtles do not drop all of their eggs at once, especially if she has not found a suitable nesting area, they are deposited a little at a time sometimes over the course of 2-5 weeks ( normal time with sufficient nest 1-8 days), so watch for more! If she has more later on during this 2-5 week period keep a close eye on her for signs of distress, the longer she waits to drop them the more calcium build up in the egg shells making them harder than softer and not as easy to pass. There is a way to check her gravid spot to see if she has more eggs tucked inside, but be careful not to put too much pressure on her when feeling around, it could cause damage to her eggs.

Please see link below for tips on how to build her a good nesting area (necessary to have whether she has a boyfriend or not).

http://animals.mom.me/build-nesting-box-turtle-aquarium-8089.html